# Best way to register event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mouseevent, angular, jqlite

As far as I know, we can use `.bind` and `.on` api from jqlite or `.addEventListener` native api to register event. Many people are using jqlite api to register event since angular 1.x offers that. But what about Angular 2? Does Angular 2 still offers jqlite api, or should we stick with the native api since it is safer that way.

Also, regarding the performance between `.on` and `.addEventListener` . Which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't touch the DOM directly in angular2 application. It makes impossible to run your application in `WebWorker`s or on a server side. Use `(event)="someHanlder()"` notation instead. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jm36x6nXXUrvebgZtrQa?p=preview).

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    // in "template" you can add handlers for child elements events
    template: `
        <button (click)="handleClickChild($event)">here</b>
    `,
    // in "host" you can add handlers for host element events
    host: {
        '(click)': 'handleClickHost($event)'
    }
})
class SomeComponent {
    handleClickHost(event) {
        // some logic
    }
    handleClickChild(event) {
        // some login
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does Angular 2 still offers jqlite api, or should we stick with the native api since it is safer that way.

Angular 2 does not offer jqlite.

> Also, regarding the performance between .on and .addEventListener . Which one is better

Use `.addEventListener` as that is the DOM official way.

Comment: with addEventListener you can face the multiplecalls event